# How much time does sulfur dioxide take to oxidize to trioxide in air?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I saw that $\ce{NO2}$ is oxidized really fast, but if I put $\ce{SO2}$ in a jar with air at STP, will it take hours, days or years to react into $\ce{SO3}?$

Comment: I'd say it will take days if you add some water, or even longer otherwise.

Comment: In the reaction $\ce{O + SO2 +M \to SO3 + M }$ in the gas phase and where $M$ is an inert gas such as He the rate constant is $3\cdot 10^{14}\,\mathrm{cm^6\,mol^{-2}\,s^{-1}}$.  See Westernberg & deHaas J. Chem. Phys. 63, 5411 (1975); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.431347. Usually in the manufacture of sulphuric acid the oxidation is done with a catalyst such as $\ce{V2O5}$.